# lme models yielding different coefficients for the same fixed effect but different random effects

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I'm doing a linear mixed model. I have six repeated measures of subjects which correspond to different time's instants of some dependent variables.
Using the `lme` function of the `nlme` package in R, I've fitted two linear mixed models with one fixed effect, one using the time variable as a random effect, and another using the IDs as a random effect variable.
So that:

```
model_1 <- lme(response ~ beta, random = ~1|TIME, data = df, method = "REML")
model_2 <- lme(response ~ beta, random = ~1|ID, data = df, method = "REML")
```

However, I find that the two models differ in the coefficient estimates, those still remaining very similar.
Particularly, the coefficients of the first model, the one with time as random effect, corresponds to the mean of the observations within each times as in the original dataset.
However, when modelling ID as a random effect, I don't find these estimates to be the same.

I'm a bit perplexed by this and would greatly appreciate some guidance on understanding this behavior.

Comment: If your observations are collected at meaningfully different times and/or if you're interested in an effect over time, it should almost certainly be a fixed effect. There's not a lot of detail to go on here, but you are fitting two very different models: the first assumes that all subjects share a random effects parameter per timepoint, whereas the second assumes that all timepoints share one per subject.

Comment: What about this perplexes you?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no interactions in the data, and if the random effect is uncorrelated with the covariate, then there's no reason to expect that the fixed component of the model would change by adding random effects. Recall: an interaction is a structural change in the slope relating your X (beta) to your Y (response). Maybe you can draw some examples or simulations to convince yourself. What does change in these scenarios *may be* the overall inference/significance test for the covariate as a regressor in the model.

Comment: if I fit two simpler models like these two:
```model_3 <- lme(response ~ as.factor(Time), random = ~1|ID,
 data = df, method = "REML") ``` and 
```model_4<- lme(response ~ as.factor(Time), random = ~1|Time,
 data = df, method = "REML") ```
I should see no differences in the coefficients... but that's not what i see.

Comment: In the latter example the random effect is *not* uncorrelated with the covariate.

Comment: Does this mean that the model takes into account the correlation between consecutive time points? What I would like to see is the mean `response` at each time, accounting for the differences within different subjects coming from having 6 measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Model_2 is a way of adjusting for clustering of time points within ID. We're asking the model to estimate a random intercept value for each ID; conditional on this intercept, the observations for a given ID are assumed to be independent. But there's no accounting for any time effect here.
As PBulls notes, we can treat Time as a fixed effect, essentially estimating a mean for each time point, assuming Time is treated as a factor. One option would be:

```r
model_3 <- lme(response ~ beta + as.factor(Time), random = ~1|ID,
 data = df, method = "REML")
```

Sometimes we estimate a linear Time slope, where Time is again included as a fixed effect, but defined as a continuous variable (eg, months from baseline). In this case, in addition to including a random ID intercept, we sometimes include a *random* Time slope, allowing the time slope for each ID to vary randomly around the average Time slope. This isn't what model_1 is doing, though.

Comment: what if I estimate a model with Time as the only covariate and ID as random effect? 

`model_3 <- lme(response ~ as.factor(Time), random = ~1|ID,
 data = df, method = "REML") `

Comment: Then you're modelling the mean response at each `Time`, with an additional random intercept for each `ID`.

Comment: This could be a reasonable model, depending on the context. I'm not sure what variable 'beta' represents, but it can likely be included as a fixed effect if you need it. With repeated measures, one concern is that measurements closer to each other in time may be more strongly correlated, which your model_3 (which assumes a covariance structure called 'compound symmetry') wouldn't take into account. It could still be adequate, depending on the data and context.